# Migrate Users from keycloak to Firebase with Python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, migration, keycloak

We have switched from Keycloak authentication to Firebase authentication and I need to migrate the users from Keycloak to Firebase using Python.
These users were stored by Keycloak in a Postgres DB. I used the Admin SDK to get the users out of the Postgres DB and have already successfully saved them to Firebase, using the instructions from Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users. The users are also successfully created and displayed in Firebase. The users who logged in with the identity provider like Google Auth. can log in without problems. Only those users who log in with email and password get an error message INVALID_PASSWORD, CODE:400.
My guess then was that the salt and/or hash are not passed correctly or that they are stored wrong (keycloak hashing alg.:pbkdf2_sha256 and iterations: 27500 (default value)).
When passing in Python to the firebase attributes: password_hash and password_salt a byte array is expected, which I convert with bytes(user.password_hash/.password_salt, encoding='utf-8') to a byte
array. In some posts (like https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/issues/182) I saw that I should decode the hash in base64 and after that it should already work.

```py
users = []
for user in list_users:        
    record = auth.ImportUserRecord(
        uid=user.uid,
        email= user.email,
        display_name= user.display_name,
        email_verified= user.email_verified,
        password_hash= None if user.password_hash is None else ab64_decode(bytes(user.password_hash, encoding='utf-8')),
        password_salt= None if user.password_salt is None else bytes(user.password_salt, encoding='utf-8'),
        provider_data= None if user.providers == [] else getProviderRecords(user.providers),
    )
    users.append(record)
```

But what I know is that keycloak already stores hash and salt in format base 64 into the DB. The salt was also tested by me with an online tool (https://8gwifi.org/pbkdf.jsp) and it could validate. When saving in Firebase I don't get an exception and I also reconstructed the saving of the hash (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/blob/master/firebase_admin/_user_import.py).
However, there could be something wrong with auth.UserImportHash, but I also got this code from the Firebase instructions.

```py
iteraions_round=27500
hash_alg = auth.UserImportHash.pbkdf2_sha256(rounds=iteraions_round)
try:
    result = auth.import_users(users, hash_alg=hash_alg)
    print('Successfully imported {0} users. Failed to import {1} users.'.format(
        result.success_count, result.failure_count))
    for err in result.errors:
        print('Failed to import {0} due to {1}'.format(users[err.index].uid, err.reason))
except exceptions.FirebaseError:
    # Some unrecoverable error occurred that prevented the operation from running.
    pass
```

Also, I output the users again before saving, but password_hash and password_salt are also saved with b'hash/salt' as in the Firebas instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If the salt is stored as a base64 encoded string, you have to decode that before passing it to Firebase. The code above only seems to decode the password hash." [hiranya911](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/issues/563)

following code worked as expected:

```py
...
password_hash= None if user.password_hash is None else ab64_decode(bytes(user.password_hash, encoding='utf-8')),
password_salt= None if user.password_salt is None else ab64_decode(bytes(user.password_salt, encoding='utf-8')),
...
```